# GameProgramming, Prototype pattern: How to translate generic class from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, class, generics, prototype-programming

In this fascinating book called Game Programming Patterns, in the Prototype example, the author shows how to use generic class to spawn a monster in a game.

Disclaimer: The author does state that the code is merely for giving an example to a concept (and might not be perfect)

This is the C++ code in the given example:

```
class Spawner
{
public:
  virtual ~Spawner() {}
  virtual Monster* spawnMonster() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class SpawnerFor : public Spawner
{
public:
  virtual Monster* spawnMonster() { return new T(); }
};
```

The calling class would run:

```
Spawner* ghostSpawner = new SpawnerFor<Ghost>();
```

I've tried to translate this example to C#, so it can be tested in Unity in a scene:

```
public class Spawner<T> {
    public virtual Monster SpawnMonster() {
        return null;
    }
}

class SpawnerTemplate<T> : Spawner { 
    public override Monster SpawnMonster() {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

The script from within the scene would run:

```
  var ghost = new Spawner<Ghost>();
```

Visual Studio would not compile and so I rewrote to following:

```
class SpawnerTemplate<T> : Spawner where T : new(){ 
    public override Monster SpawnMonster() {
        return new T() as Monster;
    }
}
```

A compilation error remained when calling:

```
var ghost = new SpawnerTemplate<Ghost>();
```

*must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter*

This is how the Ghost code looks like:

```
public class Ghost : Monster
{
    public Ghost (int health, int speed) {
        this.health = health;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public override Monster Clone() {
        return new Ghost(health, speed);
    }
}
```

Is my translation from C++ to C# is correct?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide what your Ghost class looks like? I suspect you don't have a public Ghost() constructor defined.

Comment: Did you make sure that `Ghost` inherits from `Monster` (where `Monster` in C# is probably an interface)? Also in C#, I believe that there's a way to specify your generic must adhere to a certain interface. So you could probably say `class SpawnerTemplate<T> where T : Moster`.

Comment: I added the Ghost class to the question. Monster is a base class (but not abstract at the moment). The logic behind this code architecture is called template. I'm not sure changing the SpawnerTamplate T to be Monster, is what it is supposed to be as the SpawnerTemplate is a template of the Spawner class. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the usefulness of this pattern in C#, but:

```
public class Monster
{
}

public class Ghost : Monster
{
}

public abstract class Spawner
{
    public abstract Monster SpawnMonster();
}

public class SpawnerFor<T> : Spawner where T : Monster, new()
{
    public override Monster SpawnMonster() { return new T(); }
}
```

and then:

```
var spawnerForGhost = new SpawnerFor<Ghost>();
var ghost = spawnerForGhost.SpawnMonster();
```

The big limitation in C# is that you can define a constraint for the existance of a parameterless constructor (`, new()`), as in this example, but if for example you want your `new Monster()` to receive as something as a parameter (`new Monster(location)`), then it breaks down (you can't have constraints for parameterful constructors. You could clearly define a `public abstract Initialize(Location location)` in `Monster` and call it from the `SpawnMonster(Location location)`).